# Can =Sumproduct be edited so it always references the top row of a table?

Tags: excel-formula

Can =Sumproduct be edited to always reference the top row of a table as the primary multiplier of the line item?

This is what I have been using, but I am manually moving the first array to the top after copying the formula.  I want to pin or force it to use a specific row for the multiplier, but then remain elastic to the specifics in the units row.

- =SUMPRODUCT(C2:G2,C3:G3)
- =SUMPRODUCT(C2:G2,C4:G4)
- =SUMPRODUCT(C2:G2,C5:G5)

Also looking at INDIRECT to see if it can act as array 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]!

Answer (score 0):

So do this :

=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$G$2,C3:G3)

As you drag down the right hand array will increment...

Comment: To add to that (as it may not be clear from original answer). The `$` sign always "holds the value in place". So for example, if you wanted to change the rows on the first values, but keep the columns fixated, it would look like this `=SUMPRODUCT($C2:$G2, C3:G3)`